# How can I get rid of the message "Heads up! The branch 'master' that you pushed to was renamed to 'main'" when pushing changes to git?

Tags: git, github, git-remote

When pushing to github, I seem to always get a "Heads up!" message (below) that tells me that my `master` branch was renamed to `main`.  But I see no `main` branch on the remote `origin` repository.

**Message Example**

```
$ git push -f
...
remote:
remote: Heads up! The branch 'master' that you pushed to was renamed to 'main'.
remote:
```

I've checked everything I could think of and there is no `main` branch on origin, there is no `main` branch on local.  Where is that message coming from?

Here is a listing of my branches:

```
$ git branch --all
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Solutions Tried

I tried using `git branch -u origin/master` I've seen suggested elsewhere, but it did not help.

Comment: The "remote:" at the beginning of the message indicates that this text has come directly from the remote server you're pushing to, so what it means depends on what software and service that server is running on - e.g. Github, Gitlab, BitBucket, etc

Comment: It is Github.  The branch used to be called `main` at first, which I renamed to `master`.  I am not sure why the message from remote is saying that master was renamed to main.  Perhaps it is a misconfiguration of Github

Comment: It's not so much a *misconfiguration* of GitHub, as a feature GitHub added (probably because users were pestering GitHub Support, but that's just my guess) that you personally find annoying. So you just need a way to turn it off. There might be a simpler way than your sequence of pushes, but hey, it *worked!* That's what matters here. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by issuing a series of commands:

First, I renamed `master` to `random` on Github, and then I ran

```
git branch -m random
git push origin HEAD -f # pushed changes to new branch "random"

git push origin :master # deleted master that was hanging there somehow

git commit --amend -a --no-edit # to force a commit change
git push -u origin random -f # no message!
```

I then reversed this process => renamed branch `random` to `master` on GitHub, and

```
git push origin :random
git branch -m master
git push -u origin master
git remote prune origin
git push
```

no more message!

Comment: Yes, the natural basic recipe that works is this: Do the claimed renaming directly on Github and then do the inverse renaming: Rename `master` to `main`, then `main` to `master`. If you had the problem for anything other than `master` (I once did!), you need to make the problematic branch the Github default branch first to be able to rename it directly in the Github UI (at repository->Settings->Branches).